# Reporting Services Report Deployment / downgrading problem

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, bids

I have a reporting services project with lots of reports developed in SQL server business intelligence development studio that comes with sql server 2008. I want to deploy these reports to a server that has reporting services 2005 only but the deployment is failing. I'm wondering if any one around here has been able to deploy reports developed in business intelligence development studio 2008 to a server running reporting services 2005 only.

If it isn't passible, is there a way of downgrading my report project back to reporting services 2005 so i can be able to deploy my reports?.

Comment: The same happened when you deployed a report developed using VS 2005 onto an SSRS 2000 box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not currently possible.

The following thread contains a discussion from the MSDN forums pertaining to a similar query. If you read through it, you will discover that an MVP raised this as a development/support request with Mcrosoft.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/686cac48-bc14-4978-b7bf-acbc0c90384e/

Answer (score 0):

Is it really that bad?

For going from 2005 -> 2000, you just had to strip a couple of lines of xml out of the rdl file.

Can't you do something similar? Assuming you don't use 08 specific things like Tablix

?

Comment: You wouldn't be able to create much of a report without Tablix in 08.  The list, matrix and table reports are all just Tablix impelementations in 08.

Comment: what i have found out is that the reports that were upgraded can be downgraded, but its a dirty hack. It seems there is no way out though for those rdl files created right from 2008 desinger.

Comment: ObjectInstance, could you post the details of your downgrading hack?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft, you don't know how huge of a pain in the butt this problem is. And we're left to find out about this incompatibility only after creating reports in VS 2008 and trying to run them on SQL Server 2005.

This is extremely poor product management on Microsoft's part.